# PGAdmin Edit data

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm new to Postgres and can't seem to edit the data in the table. The test box pops up but doesn't allow me to change the text. This initial table didn't have any PK or SERIAL. So I added them and my table definition is now this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.weather
(
city character varying(80) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
temp_lo integer,
temp_hi integer,
prcp real,
date date,
id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('weather_id_seq'::regclass),
CONSTRAINT weather_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.weather
OWNER to postgres;
```

It's probably very simple

Comment: Do you mean you want to edit the data in PGAdmin's UI, or using a query you submit to PGAdmin?

Comment: PGAdmin's UI, much like you can in PHPMyAdmin

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Right-click on your table, select `View Data/View All Rows` (or one of the variants). That window will let you edit the data. Then press F6 to save changes (with thanks to leverglowh for pointing that out).

Comment: I have no idea what witchcraft you have employed there, but thanks. I could have sworn I did that

Comment: Just remember to press F6 to save changes

Comment: Of course. Quick google search and now I know `F6`

Comment: yes, F6 is the magic key here since none of the GUI buttons function to save. Thank you!

Comment: if it's a boolean, press enter before F6, otherwise the checkbox has not really been changed

Comment: Any idea if it's possible to preview the SQL that will run? Just pressing F6 and having it do *something* makes me uber nervous.

Comment: Behind the scenes it will only be issuing the appropriate update command but if you're concerned just issue the update manually in a script window.

Comment: What is this F6 shortcut for? i.e. is there a way to execute this same action via the interface? I'm on a mac, which has no F buttons.

Comment: @Nodeocrat - Don't know about the Mac, I'm afraid. On the PC F6 saves altered data back to the database. This is still the case with the latest PG Admin V. 5

Comment: pgAdmin v6. Monterey the fourth icon from the left on the lower toolbar works. Looks like a stack of coins (disks) with a small image of a floppy disk (I think this icon needs updating). Unfortunately the manual rarely (ever) shows images of the icons. Rollover does say "Save data changes (F6)". I can't use F6 since I have it mapped to something else and changing is for pgAdmin would make it worse.

Comment: @AdamBenson `F6` did worked very well. Thanks for the great help.

Comment: very intuitive.

Answer (score 22):

With pgadmin 4.6 the icon has changed (see screenshot):

[image: save data icon]

a zoom to the icon:

[image: save data icon zoom]

You can also use the shortcut F6.

Answer (score 9):

Right-click on your table, select `View/Edit Data` -> `All Rows`:

[image]

Then there is an icon in the top bar, looking like a table with an arrow pointing down (the icon on the right of the screenshot below):

[image: The icon on the right in the picture.]

The icon is gray but works nevertheless.

Answer (score 4):

[image: PgAdmin Save]

There is an image like Database with Save icon to save the edited data in the table

Answer (score 2):

The above solutions all work for the specific case of the question, but I found that they did not work for me.

The reason is that my table did not have a primary key. As said on [pgAdmin's official page](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/editgrid.html):

> To modify the content of a table, each row in the table must be
> uniquely identifiable. If the table definition does not include an OID
> or a primary key, the displayed data is read only.

I had believed that including:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.mytable(
    id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, [...]);
```

would automatically assign id as the primary key. I was wrong and thus could not edit "mytable" in pgAdmin.

Once I entered:

```
ALTER TABLE public.mytable
ADD CONSTRAINT mytable_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

The problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to save updated data in PGAdmin:

1. Using shortcut key: F6
2. Using button in image above

[image]